# Would Stack Exchange take action against posting copyrighted material? (considered fair use)

Tags: discussion, copyright

## I just want to make sure that I don't get in trouble with Stack Exchange for posting this image.

I have written a paper that is a specific rebuttal to the proof contained in the image. I didn't even need to copy the whole proof, I skipped the last page. To the best of my knowledge this is allowed as "fair use" on the basis that its purpose is academic scholarship and the fact that a rebuttal of a proof is very much transformative relative to the original proof.

https://fairuse.stanford.edu/overview/fair-use/four-factors/

**Linz, Peter 1990**. An Introduction to Formal Languages and Automata. Lexington/Toronto: D. C. Heath and Company (317-319).

[image: Peter Linz Proof]

Comment: Posting the image in question *while asking if it's okay* is... an odd way to go about asking.

Comment: I want a 100% specific answer. If it is not OK then I can delete the image. I want to eliminate the possibility of Stack Exchange taking punitive action on some future date regarding this image.

Comment: Nobody here can definitively answer your question, only give you conjectures based on their understanding of fair use. This isn't a place for legal advice. As well, we generally do not appreciate images of large blocks of text here.

Comment: @animuson I am not asking for legal advice. I am asking for Stack Exchange rules advice.

Comment: No, you are asking for legal advice. We have nothing to say on the issue and you would not ever get an answer to this question from an employee.

Comment: @animuson I just want to make sure that Stack Exchange will not take preemptive action. To the best of my knowledge my use is fair use. I am not asking SE to weigh in on other side of this.

Comment: We would only ever take action if we received a DMCA complaint from the copyright holder, which does not necessarily have anything to do with fair use. You could *contest* that takedown notice if you believe your use falls under fair use, but that would entirely be up to you and there are legal ramifications if it comes to that. We cannot tell you whether it does or does not qualify as fair use.

Comment: @animuson This is great. I just wanted to avoid the possibility that my account would be suspended by SE. Thanks for your excellent help.

Comment: A lot of this should still be plain text though.

Comment: @animuson My rebuttal of the proof (on SE) is currently much shorter than the proof. I only post the key gist of my rebuttal.

Comment: Some SE sites may enforce stricter policy about copyrighted materials than others by removing them preemptively, but SE will only take action on DMCA takedown request

Comment: @MetaAndrewT. I just wanted to make sure that I would not be banned without warning. I correctly refuted the Linz Halting problem proof, so including the proof that I refuted is allowed under fair use.

Comment: You *should* have explicit or implicit permission to post any content created by others, but if you don't, that's *your* concern, not Stack Exchange's.

Comment: I certainly agree that [images of text](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/33091/207316) are not desirable, but I guess you don't have much option if you're posting on a site which doesn't support MathJax. Also, your image contains diagrams that would otherwise need to be posted as separate images anyway.

Comment: @PM2Ring I could post a PDF that has been processed by OCR, yet SE cannot handle PDF. I could transform the text into MathJax, yet want the readers to perfectly know that the original was not changed at all. The image is 1000 DPI so it prints very well.

Comment: Another option is SVG. SE can display SVG (including animations), you just can't host it on imgur. You can see a simple example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4011941/207316).

Comment: You can always include both the MathJax **and** images of the equations if you'd like to include screenshots that prove your MathJax is accurate. (It's ridiculous that browsers can't natively handle formatting math equations but that's a rant for a different time/place.)

Comment: @BSMP For my purposes an image is good enough on SE. Non SE reviewers can examine the PDF version.

Answer (score 0):

From a [comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/365098/can-i-post-this-image-to-stack-exchange-under-fair-use#comment1218656_365098) by animuson:

> We would only ever take action if we received a DMCA complaint from the copyright holder, which does not necessarily have anything to do with fair use. You could contest that takedown notice if you believe your use falls under fair use, but that would entirely be up to you and there are legal ramifications if it comes to that. We cannot tell you whether it does or does not qualify as fair use.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen DMCA takedowns happen on Stack Overflow ([example](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/376183/6083675)). It's quite rare and when it does happen, it only results in posts getting deleted. Here's what the process looks like:

1. The copyright owner finds their content online and sends an email to Stack Exchange requesting a takedown.
2. If SE believes that there's a chance it's an infringement, they delete the question or answer with the content, leaving a comment as to why.
3. It's possible for the person whose post was removed to file a counter claim to try to get their post undeleted.

Only the copyright owner can tell you if your post has gone too far with using their content. So, if you're that uncomfortable with it, you should ask them for permission.

Comment: Copyright law's "Fair use" overrules the copyright owner. It is very reasonable that Stack Exchange err on their safe side to protect themselves.